# Find and replace matching html tags

Tags: html, replace

I want to transform some of the opening and closing tags in an html document to other tags. That is I would like to transform

```
<div class='foo'> This is some text. </div>
```

to something like

```
 <p> This is some text </p>.
```

Is there a way to find and replace matching html tags?

Comment: I strongly recommend not using a regex for this; they're not the right tool for the job. I think `html-mode` or `nxml-mode` will have structures editing commands for this. I'm not at my computer or I'd look them up.

Comment: [Have you tried using an XML Parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @omajid @db48x I am not planning to use `regexp-replace` to scan and replace the html tags. I want to know what I should use to parse and modify XML in emacs.

Comment: Ah, in that case the 'query-replace tag is confusing :)

Comment: How about creating a few macros for the purpose?

Comment: @myTerminal: If that doesn't already exist I might. To be clear: do you mean keyboard macros or emacs lisp macros?

Comment: @Dan I mean Emacs Lisp macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `nxml-mode`, first customize `nxml-sexp-element-mode` to `t`. Then normal Emacs commands like `forward-sexp`, `backward-sexp`, and `kill-sexp` will work on elements, not just start or end tags.

Starting with `"|<div class='foo'> This is some text. </div>"` (where the | illustrates the cursor position), doing `C-M-d C-M-k C-M-u C-M-k <p C-c C-i C-y M-y` will replace the div with a paragraph. That's quite easy to record as a keyboard macro, although of course it'll only ever replace the tag after point with a paragraph; if you want more flexibility you'll have to write a function that prompts for the new tag to insert first.